# How can I access 2 items of (item in items) in one iteration using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make my menu page have to buttons side by side but I need to make 2 buttons at once using ng-repeat anyone have a suggestion as to another approach or is there a way to do this with ng-repeat

here is my html code for this partial view

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="buttons in menuButtons | exactMatchFilter">

        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">

        <!--Button 1-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="goToView1()">{{buttons[0].info}}</button>
            </div>

           <!--Button 2-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="goToView1()">{{buttons[1].info}}</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only added the buttons[1], [0] so you can see what im trying to do i know that you cant add index's here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write buttons object like this

```
var buttons = { 
 one: { info: 'someinfo'},
 two: { info: 'someInfo' }
};
```

then in ng-repeat you can just like this

```
<!--Button 1-->
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="goToView1()">{{buttons.one.info}}</button>
</div>

<!--Button 2-->
   <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="goToView1()">{{buttons.two.info}}</button>
   </div>
```

If you want to do this at once you may need to write custom ng-directive.

```
  angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.button = {
        one: {info: 'some info'},
        two: {info: 'other info'}
      };
    }])
    .directive('myButtons', function() {
      return {
        template: '<button>{{button.one.info}}</button> <button>{{button.two.info}}</button>'
      };
    });
```